# System.Data.DataColumnCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Count'

Tags: c#, vb.net, ado.net

Am trying to copy a collection into a new collection. The code is running within a Blue Prism Code stage, which is not normal C# writing code like main etc.

The inputs  I have are Source_Collection as System.Data.DataTable, Start_Row as System.Decimal and Number_of_Rows_to_Copy as System.Decimal.

Outputs are: Output_Collection as  System.Data.DataTable, Success as boolean and Error_Message as String.

The code is compiled within BP, but is not doing it's main stuff, which is to copy and input collection into an output one.

```
try {
    int SR = Convert.ToInt32(Start_Row);            
                            
 // Set up the new collection with columns
Output_Collection = new DataTable();
int loopTo = Source_Collection.Columns.Count - 1;
for (int J= 0;  J <= loopTo; J++) {
        Output_Collection.Columns.Add(Source_Collection.Columns[J].ColumnName, Source_Collection.Columns[J].DataType);
    }
                                
                                // copy the requested rows one by one
int loopTo1 = Convert.ToInt32(SR + Number_of_Rows_to_Copy - 1);
int loopTo2 =  Source_Collection.Columns.Count - 1;
for (int I= SR;  I <= loopTo1; I++) {
    // object[,] Values = new object (Source_Collection.Columns.Count() - 1);
    var Values = new object[Source_Collection.Columns.Count-1];

    for (int J= 0; J <= loopTo2; J++) {

               Values[J]= Source_Collection.Rows[I][J];
                                    }        
            Output_Collection.Rows.Add(Values);                            
        }
        Success =true;
        Error_Message = null;
}
catch (Exception Ex) {
        Success = false;
        Error_Message = Ex.Message;
        Output_Collection=null;

}
```

This code doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work? Where is the error? `Count` is definitely available. The code though is over-complicated. Whatever it's trying to do, there are probably many duplicate questions that show how it's done. BluePrism has nothing to do with it, this is just ADO.NET calls.

Comment: Is this trying to clone a DataTable? [DataTable.Clone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.clone?view=netframework-4.8) is a built-in method. Even without it, it's pointless to create a new `object` array to get the row's values. That's available through [DataRow.ItemArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.itemarray?view=netframework-4.8)